# To print result from Response.Write in text box

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm learning to code in C#. I wrote this code to print the table on web.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string str = TextBox1.Text;
    //Response.Write(str);
    int i = System.Convert.ToInt32(str);

    for (int x = 0; x < 11; x++)
    {
        int result = i * x;
        Response.Write(i+" x "+x+" = "+result+"<br/>");
    }

}
```

As soon as I submit the value obtain from text box, it prints the multiplication table for that number (If the number typed is 45) as follows:

```
45 x 0 = 0
45 x 1 = 45
45 x 2 = 90
45 x 3 = 135
45 x 4 = 180
45 x 5 = 225
45 x 6 = 270
45 x 7 = 315
45 x 8 = 360
45 x 9 = 405
45 x 10 = 450
```

Now I want to print this whole result in the textbox. Please help me!!

Comment: do you want to print this pattern in 10 different textboxes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First set property of textbox to multiline then use following

```
TextBox1.Text = "";
for (int x = 0; x < 11; x++)
{
     int result = i * x;
     TextBox1.Text += String.Format("{0} x {1} = {2}\n", i,x,result);
}
```

Assuming you want to print it in same Textbox in which number was entered.

Comment: @Joel Coehoorn I was thinking of it but is it ok to use String.Format every time?

Comment: [It's fine for something this small.](http://blog.codinghorror.com/the-sad-tragedy-of-micro-optimization-theater/) I made the change because I wanted to edit for the indentation and int/string type mismatch, too. This seemed the easier fix.

Answer (score 2):

For fun:

```
int i = int.Parse(TextBox1.Text);
var lines = Enumerable.Range(0, 11)
              .Select(x => String.Format("{0} x {1} = {2}", i,x,i * x));
TextBox1.Text = String.Join("\n", lines);
```

Don't forget to set TextBox1's `Multiline` property to `True`.